# MYSQLI Insert into doesnt work with no error

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

This is my Code:

```
$stmt = $db_main->prepare("INSERT INTO `persons` (`type`, `type_id`, `user_id`) VALUES ('event_organizer', ?, ?)");         
if ($mysqli_error = mysqli_error($db_main))
    die("MYSQLI_ERROR " . $mysqli_error);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $event_id, $user_id);
```

The Mysql-Statement

```
INSERT INTO `persons` 
(`type`, `type_id`, `user_id`) 
VALUES 
('event_organizer', ?, ?)
```

If I run it I get the error:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in [...] on line 4.
```

But I don't get why. Tablename and Columnnames are correct. $event_id and $user_id are set (24 and 25). The Connection works correct, the SQL-Querys before works correct.

Comment: where is your `$db_main` ? you can try it like this `$stmt->bind_param('sii', 'event_organizer', $event_id, $user_id);`

Comment: $db_main is declared in another PHP file which is included by include_once('[...]'); And I think, that $db_main has to be declared correctly, because the SQL-Query before works and it uses the same database! Binding 'event_organizer' itself or with another variable doesn't work either :/
I really don't see my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake! I forget to close the statement before. After I did this, everything works correctly.

But:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sii', 'event_organizer', $event_id, $user_id);
```

isn't working. You have to bind variables!